# Is it possible to run a Python interpreter within a Flutter app?

Tags: python, android, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and trying it for the first time (I'm not an experienced mobile developer either) and was wondering how to go about running a Python interpreter within my app.

What I'd actually like to create is an app with Python katas or challenges so that when the user solves a challenge it will tell them if it passed some tests (I assume I'd write those as unit tests).

Not sure where to start with all of that, though... I'm not even sure Flutter is the best choice, but since it sounds so promising and I can compile my app for both Android and iOS, I decided to give it a go. So any guidance on how to start building this app would be very welcome.

Comment: If my answer answers your question I would appreciate marking it and upvoting it.

Comment: I am exploring along this. Using Kivy's buildozer to build some .so libraries for both android and ios and including those .so files in flutter file structures seems like an easy path, though I have yet actually tried. The new FFI feature of flutter can be used to access these .so libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TL;DR: Yes, it is possible.
```

As there are a number of Python related apps on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=python&c=apps), to include a [full port of Python 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3), I believe it is definitely possible to run Python on an Android app. The difficulty is in making it happen.

Actually creating that integration is something I am also researching. Resources I have run across so far:

- [Flutter packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) - This is the route I am currently attempting,
  so I cannot help much yet past this list
- [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - Integration here has a learning curve (just like Android Studio) but development seems a little smoother than AS
- [QPython](https://www.qpython.com/) - runs Python on Android devices; no personal experience on this yet
- [BeeWare](https://beeware.org/) - again, no personal experience with this
- [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) - not an easy integration
  from my experience; graphics creation is much more involved than native Android development
- [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) - per the developer, this is still maintained. Supports Java and Python on Android. It does have a supported [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) plugin, which is easier to use while integrating with flutter app.

Comment: Chaquopy developer here: it is quite definitely still supported, and I'd be interested to know why you thought it wasn't. I don't know how easy it would be to use with Flutter though, and it's only available for Android, not iOS.

Comment: When I tried to install it (almost a year ago now) I ran across issues that could not be solved for Python 3, but I don't remember what it was specifically. Good to see you are still developing it.

Answer (score 1):

@Floella, I have created [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) plugin, by using this plugin, you can use chaquopy sdk in your flutter android app. This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U5cgTkP-Wc) I have made that demonstrate the chaquopy plugin in action.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Flython](https://pub.dev/packages/flython) to run the python script.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: thanks for point out, i have edited my answer.

Comment: you don't seem to have understood what I'm asking. did you read the page I linked you to? I'm asking if you are affiliated in any way with the Flython project.

Comment: no, i dont have any affliation with Flython project.